# AngularJs validation, all inputs must have different values

Tags: angularjs

There can be 1 or more inputs. All inputs must have different values. How to create such validation(directive)? If user enters non-unique value in some input - it should be highlighted as invalid.

For now I just have html template without validation

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm">
                <md-input-container ng-repeat="(key, item) in data">
                    <label>{{labels[item.id]}}</label>
                    <input ng-model="data[key].number" required>
                </md-input-container>

                <md-button ng-click="save()" class="md-raised md-button md-primary" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">
                    Save
                </md-button>
            </form>
```

Update.
I managed to solve this with ng-change directive:

Template is the same except:

```
<input ng-model="data[key].number" name="number_{{key}}" required ng-change="validate(key, myForm)">
```

validate function in controller:

```
$scope.validate = function(key, myForm) {
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if(i == key) continue;

            if(data[i].number === data[key].number){
                myForm['number_' + key].$setValidity("unique", false);
                return;
            }else{
                myForm['number_' + key].$setValidity("unique", true);
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Looks like your homework, no? please show your code

Comment: @MaximShoustin For now I just have html template without validation (edited question)

Comment: can u please post an example of `data` list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `ng-change` instead of a directive. You can pass `controlName` and `inputValue` into your function and can do proper validation

Answer (score 1):

You can write some directive that blocklist prev typed values.

Something like:

```
app.directive('blacklist', function (){ 
   return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
          var blacklist = attr.blacklist.split(',');
          ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function (value) {
            // here you can parse the data
             ngModel.$setValidity('blacklist', blacklist.indexOf(value) === -1);
             return value;
          });
      }
   };
});
```

and:

```
 <input ng-model="data[key].number" blacklist="data" required>
```

<kbd>[Some Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/kQwaGTmCltgIUbkB)</kbd>

It will give you some insight